# How to Properly install Ubuntu Server 18.04 with RAID1? Getting a /boot error

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, raid

I am installing Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS on my home server system and would like to RAID1 my 120GB Kingston SSD's. Now, I understand that the boot partition cannot be on a software raid, as it has to be on a physical local disk. I've done that, but the installer does not let me proceed, giving me a warning along the lines of:

> Must mount a partition of a local disk to /boot However, I've mounted a 512MB fat32 partition to /boot/efi

In fact, if I mark the empty disk as a boot device, the installer automatically creates and mounts the same partition.[You can click here to see an image of my partition scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aoao3.jpg).

The 512MB partition on the second disk is for a fallback to install/copy bootloader files to in the event of a disk failure.